# How to detect an instance data attribute change when debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, monkeypatching

I am trying to debug a multi-threaded program that uses a third-party package.

At some point, one of the attributes of an object (that is not created directly by me) is changed and I can't figure out what changed it. I could not find anything in my code that changes it.

Since this is a third-party package, I prefer not to change its code directly, but rather patch it from the outside as necessary.

My plan was to somehow tap into or wrap the code that sets the attribute and set a breakpoint or print the stack trace from there.

I tried monkey-patching the `__setattr__` method of the instance, but it was not triggered.

I also tried to patch the class itself:

```
def patch_class(target):

    def method(self, name, value):
        print(name, value)
        print("called from", target)
        setattr(self, name, value) # break or print trace here

    target.__setattr__ = types.MethodType(method, target)

patch_class(WebSocket)
```

but then all of the attributes are set on the class itself, as the method is bound to it.

Wrapping the class with a proxy does not really help either, since I am not instantiating it myself, but rather get the instance at some point after its creation.

If it matters, the said class is *ws4py*'s `WebSocket` that is created by another third-party package, but I consider this an exercise in general debugging techniques.

Is there a more "pythonic" way of **tapping into the mutation of an existing instance**? (hack-ish ways will be appreciated as well)

Comment: What about a getter and setter for the attribute and then doing you debugging in the setter?

Comment: Well, I would prefer not to change the package code. I managed to do something using a `wrapt.ObjectProxy`, but I am wondering if there is another way. I will post it once it is stabilized.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a `__setattr__` for the class.

```
def setter_fun(self, name, value):
    print('setting', name, value)
    self.__dict__[name] = value
    if name is 'problematic_prop' and value is 'problematicValue':
        traceback.print_stack()

# and set the class setter magic method
instance.__class__.__setattr__ = setter_fun
```

It is also possible to use `setattr` instead of using the `__dict__` magic property:

```
setattr(self, name, value)
```

Now, when something sets the instance's `problematic_prop` to `problematicValue`, the stack trace will be printed:

```
>>> class A(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.foo = 1

        def set_problematic(self):
            self.problematic_prop = 'problematicValue'
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__class__.__setattr__ = setter_fun
>>> a.foo = 2
setting foo 2
>>> print(a.foo)
2
>>> a.set_problematic()
setting problematic_prop problematicValue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 6, in set_problematic
  File "<input>", line 5, in setter_fun
NameError: name 'traceback' is not defined
```

My failed attempts included either trying to attach the `__setattr__` to the instance instead of the class, or trying to attach a bound method:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def setter_fun(self, name, value):
        print('setting', name, value)
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        if name is 'problematic_prop' and value is 'problematicValue':
            traceback.print_stack()

    def set_my_function(self):
        # won't work, the function is bound to the current instance (self)
        some.instace.__class__.__setattr__ = self.setter_fun
```